# Iterating over JSON data and printing. (or creating Pandas DataFrame from JSON file)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I’m trying to use Python print specific values from a JSON file that I pulled from an API. From what I understand, I am pulling it as a JSON file that has a list of dictionaries of players, with a nested dictionary for each player containing their data (i.e. name, team, etc.).

I’m running into issues printing the values within the JSON file, as each character is printing on a separate line.

The end result I am trying to get to is a Pandas DataFrame containing all the values from the JSON file, but I can’t even seem to iterate through the JSON file correctly.

Here is my code:

```
url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/players"

querystring = {"league":"39","season":"2020", "page":"2"}

headers = {
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "xxxxxkeyxxxxx"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()

response_dump = json.dumps(response)

for item in response_dump:
    for player_item in item:
        print(player_item)
```

This is the output when I print the JSON response (first two items):

```
{'get': 'players', 'parameters': {'league': '39', 'page': '2', 'season': '2020'}, 'errors': [], 'results': 20, 'paging': {'current': 2, 'total': 37}, 'response': [{'player': {'id': 301, 'name': 'Benjamin Luke Woodburn', 'firstname': 'Benjamin Luke', 'lastname': 'Woodburn', 'age': 23, 'birth': {'date': '1999-10-15', 'place': 'Nottingham', 'country': 'England'}, 'nationality': 'Wales', 'height': '174 cm', 'weight': '72 kg', 'injured': False, 'photo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/301.png'}, 'statistics': [{'team': {'id': 40, 'name': 'Liverpool', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/40.png'}, 'league': {'id': 39, 'name': 'Premier League', 'country': 'England', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png', 'flag': 'https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg', 'season': 2020}, 'games': {'appearences': 0, 'lineups': 0, 'minutes': 0, 'number': None, 'position': 'Attacker', 'rating': None, 'captain': False}, 'substitutes': {'in': 0, 'out': 0, 'bench': 3}, 'shots': {'total': None, 'on': None}, 'goals': {'total': 0, 'conceded': 0, 'assists': None, 'saves': None}, 'passes': {'total': None, 'key': None, 'accuracy': None}, 'tackles': {'total': None, 'blocks': None, 'interceptions': None}, 'duels': {'total': None, 'won': None}, 'dribbles': {'attempts': None, 'success': None, 'past': None}, 'fouls': {'drawn': None, 'committed': None}, 'cards': {'yellow': 0, 'yellowred': 0, 'red': 0}, 'penalty': {'won': None, 'commited': None, 'scored': 0, 'missed': 0, 'saved': None}}]}, {'player': {'id': 518, 'name': 'Meritan Shabani', 'firstname': 'Meritan', 'lastname': 'Shabani', 'age': 23, 'birth': {'date': '1999-03-15', 'place': 'München', 'country': 'Germany'}, 'nationality': 'Germany', 'height': '185 cm', 'weight': '78 kg', 'injured': False, 'photo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/518.png'}, 'statistics': [{'team': {'id': 39, 'name': 'Wolves', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/39.png'}, 'league': {'id': 39, 'name': 'Premier League', 'country': 'England', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png', 'flag': 'https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg', 'season': 2020}, 'games': {'appearences': 0, 'lineups': 0, 'minutes': 0, 'number': None, 'position': 'Midfielder', 'rating': None, 'captain': False}, 'substitutes': {'in': 0, 'out': 0, 'bench': 3}, 'shots': {'total': None, 'on': None}, 'goals': {'total': 0, 'conceded': 0, 'assists': None, 'saves': None}, 'passes': {'total': None, 'key': None, 'accuracy': None}, 'tackles': {'total': None, 'blocks': None, 'interceptions': None}, 'duels': {'total': None, 'won': None}, 'dribbles': {'attempts': None, 'success': None, 'past': None}, 'fouls': {'drawn': None, 'committed': None}, 'cards': {'yellow': 0, 'yellowred': 0, 'red': 0}, 'penalty': {'won': None, 'commited': None, 'scored': 0, 'missed': 0, 'saved': None}}]},
```

This is the data type of each layer of the JSON file, from when I iterated through it with a For loop:

print(type(response))        `<class 'dict'>`

print(type(response_dump))   `<class 'str'>`

print(type(item))            `<class 'str'>`

print(type(player_item))     `<class 'str'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to `json.dumps()` in my opinion, just use the JSON from `response` to iterate:

```
for player in response['response']:
    print(player)

{'player': {'id': 301, 'name': 'Benjamin Luke Woodburn', 'firstname': 'Benjamin Luke', 'lastname': 'Woodburn', 'age': 23, 'birth': {'date': '1999-10-15', 'place': 'Nottingham', 'country': 'England'}, 'nationality': 'Wales', 'height': '174 cm', 'weight': '72 kg', 'injured': False, 'photo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/301.png'}, 'statistics': [{'team': {'id': 40, 'name': 'Liverpool', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/40.png'}, 'league': {'id': 39, 'name': 'Premier League', 'country': 'England', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png', 'flag': 'https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg', 'season': 2020}, 'games': {'appearences': 0, 'lineups': 0, 'minutes': 0, 'number': None, 'position': 'Attacker', 'rating': None, 'captain': False}, 'substitutes': {'in': 0, 'out': 0, 'bench': 3}, 'shots': {'total': None, 'on': None}, 'goals': {'total': 0, 'conceded': 0, 'assists': None, 'saves': None}, 'passes': {'total': None, 'key': None, 'accuracy': None}, 'tackles': {'total': None, 'blocks': None, 'interceptions': None}, 'duels': {'total': None, 'won': None}, 'dribbles': {'attempts': None, 'success': None, 'past': None}, 'fouls': {'drawn': None, 'committed': None}, 'cards': {'yellow': 0, 'yellowred': 0, 'red': 0}, 'penalty': {'won': None, 'commited': None, 'scored': 0, 'missed': 0, 'saved': None}}]}
{'player': {'id': 518, 'name': 'Meritan Shabani', 'firstname': 'Meritan', 'lastname': 'Shabani', 'age': 23, 'birth': {'date': '1999-03-15', 'place': 'München', 'country': 'Germany'}, 'nationality': 'Germany', 'height': '185 cm', 'weight': '78 kg', 'injured': False, 'photo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/518.png'}, 'statistics': [{'team': {'id': 39, 'name': 'Wolves', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/39.png'}, 'league': {'id': 39, 'name': 'Premier League', 'country': 'England', 'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png', 'flag': 'https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg', 'season': 2020}, 'games': {'appearences': 0, 'lineups': 0, 'minutes': 0, 'number': None, 'position': 'Midfielder', 'rating': None, 'captain': False}, 'substitutes': {'in': 0, 'out': 0, 'bench': 3}, 'shots': {'total': None, 'on': None}, 'goals': {'total': 0, 'conceded': 0, 'assists': None, 'saves': None}, 'passes': {'total': None, 'key': None, 'accuracy': None}, 'tackles': {'total': None, 'blocks': None, 'interceptions': None}, 'duels': {'total': None, 'won': None}, 'dribbles': {'attempts': None, 'success': None, 'past': None}, 'fouls': {'drawn': None, 'committed': None}, 'cards': {'yellow': 0, 'yellowred': 0, 'red': 0}, 'penalty': {'won': None, 'commited': None, 'scored': 0, 'missed': 0, 'saved': None}}]}
```

or

```
for player in response['response']:
    print(player['player'])

{'id': 301, 'name': 'Benjamin Luke Woodburn', 'firstname': 'Benjamin Luke', 'lastname': 'Woodburn', 'age': 23, 'birth': {'date': '1999-10-15', 'place': 'Nottingham', 'country': 'England'}, 'nationality': 'Wales', 'height': '174 cm', 'weight': '72 kg', 'injured': False, 'photo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/301.png'}
{'id': 518, 'name': 'Meritan Shabani', 'firstname': 'Meritan', 'lastname': 'Shabani', 'age': 23, 'birth': {'date': '1999-03-15', 'place': 'München', 'country': 'Germany'}, 'nationality': 'Germany', 'height': '185 cm', 'weight': '78 kg', 'injured': False, 'photo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/518.png'}
```

---

To get a `DataFrame` simply call `pd.json_normalize()` - Cause your question is not that clear I am not sure wiche information is needed and how to displayed. This is predestinated to ask a new question with exact that focus.:

```
pd.json_normalize(response['response'])
```

### EDIT

Based on your comment and improvment:

```
pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(response,['response'])\
          ,pd.json_normalize(response,['response','statistics'])], axis=1)\
  .drop(['statistics'], axis=1)
```

|  | player.id | player.name | player.firstname | player.lastname | player.age | player.birth.date | player.birth.place | player.birth.country | player.nationality | player.height | player.weight | player.injured | player.photo | team.id | team.name | team.logo | league.id | league.name | league.country | league.logo | league.flag | league.season | games.appearences | games.lineups | games.minutes | games.number | games.position | games.rating | games.captain | substitutes.in | substitutes.out | substitutes.bench | shots.total | shots.on | goals.total | goals.conceded | goals.assists | goals.saves | passes.total | passes.key | passes.accuracy | tackles.total | tackles.blocks | tackles.interceptions | duels.total | duels.won | dribbles.attempts | dribbles.success | dribbles.past | fouls.drawn | fouls.committed | cards.yellow | cards.yellowred | cards.red | penalty.won | penalty.commited | penalty.scored | penalty.missed | penalty.saved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 301 | Benjamin Luke Woodburn | Benjamin Luke | Woodburn | 23 | 1999-10-15 | Nottingham | England | Wales | 174 cm | 72 kg | False | https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/301.png | 40 | Liverpool | https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/40.png | 39 | Premier League | England | https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png | https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg | 2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | Attacker |  | False | 0 | 0 | 3 |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 518 | Meritan Shabani | Meritan | Shabani | 23 | 1999-03-15 | München | Germany | Germany | 185 cm | 78 kg | False | https://media.api-sports.io/football/players/518.png | 39 | Wolves | https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/39.png | 39 | Premier League | England | https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png | https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg | 2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  | Midfielder |  | False | 0 | 0 | 3 |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. Sorry, I should have clarified what I'm looking to do. I'm trying to create a table from the DataFrame that displays every single value corresponding to each player (incl. name, stats, team, etc.)

Comment: To retrieve the values of the data in the 'statistics' column, and display them as their own columns, would I use 'max_level' to go deeper?

Comment: Really helpful again, thanks so much!